# Is the correlation coefficient more than a measure of the tightness of fit?

Tags: regression, correlation, covariance, pearson-r, association-measure

or in other words, to what extent and under what conditions, the correlation coefficient can be indicative of what a regression slope signifies (in the case of a linear bivariate model)?

Comment: Please review https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: Below is my own take. However, I am not still sure if the answer is satisfactory. I wish to know what the community agrees with the answer and if the answer can be improved?
 https://globalalternatives.wordpress.com/2021/10/21/the-correlation-coefficient-is-certainly-more-than-a-measure-of-the-tightness-of-fit/

Comment: I understand that this question has been raised before but I am approaching it from a different angle (check the above link). As a new contributor, I am not allowed to add my answer to the question raised before because I do not have enough reputation!! so from where I am supposed to start, I do not know. my questions have been closed multiple times and there is always a reason for it! do we really need to be that strict? seriously?

Comment: Related: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237436551_Thirteen_Ways_to_Look_at_the_Correlation_Coefficient

Comment: Related: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2684692

Comment: @Galen Hi, thanks, interesting sources! I will read them certainly. how come these oldies have scaped my attention! until then I wonder what you think of the piece I have written on my weblog. it would be great if you could kindly share your thoughts. https://globalalternatives.wordpress.com/2021/10/21/the-correlation-coefficient-is-certainly-more-than-a-measure-of-the-tightness-of-fit/

Comment: Your blog gives me the impression that you might appreciate [a first-principles view of mathematical statistics](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Measure_Theory_and_Probability_Theory/XT3-jUc3anEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover). The pure math will offer you greater precision in what correlation is and isn't.

Comment: thanks a lot @Glen for your immediate response and for introducing the book. I will look into it. Cheers.